# Task.Run(() => { ends without doing anything

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Anyone knows why the `Task.Run` below just ends without doing anything, while if only keep that line:

```
var someDump = Helper.MakeRequest(body, Helper.GetUrl(2, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeId"]), 2);
```

it will work seamlessly??

Thank you!

PS: It will just print out "t2 done".

```
var t2 = Task.Run(() => 
{
   string filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerPoolsFile"]);

   var someDump = Helper.MakeRequest(body, Helper.GetUrl(2, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeId"]), 2);

   JObject wfOutput = JObject.Parse(someDump.WFOutput);
   var jsonData = wfOutput["output-parameters"];
   var poolsList = jsonData[0]["value"]["string"]["value"];
   JObject siteJson = JObject.Parse(poolsList.ToString());
   filePath = filePath + "_" + siteJson["site"].ToString() + ".json";

   if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
   {
      // Create a file to write to.
      using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(filePath))
      {
         sw.WriteLine(poolsList.ToString());
      }
   }
   else
   {
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, poolsList.ToString());
   }

}).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("t2 done."));
Task.Yield();
```

Comment: ***Pro Tip*** : If you want people to read your code, format it in a way that is normal for most people to read

Comment: Also explain why you have decided to `Yield`, why are you using `ContinueWith`, and why you are not just *awaiting* the `Task.Run`. At the moment you have a splattering of code with no explanation as to why you are doing these things, what you hope to achieve or your constraints. Our only guess is that you have no idea what any of these things do, in which case you should just `await` the `Task.Run` remove both the `ContinueWith`, and `Yield`

Comment: I use Yield, because it's in a "public static void" method, not in a async one. The ContinueWith with log me the end of the task, for debugging purposes. Hope it's clear enough now??

Comment: @Delgado, I would avoid the use of Yield if possible. You can also change the signature to "public static Task" which is the same but then for async functions. If a async function returns nothing, then use Task as a return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to await the task at the end:

```
await t2;
```

Your function exits before the task had a chance to finish

Comment: I'm tempted to edit your text. Did you mean _**exits** before the task had a chance to finish_?

Comment: Long day, I should go to sleep. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: No problem. Completely understand. It's been an unusually long day today.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates two tasks, not just one. This code:

```
var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    //...
}).ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("t2 done."));
```

...is equivalent to this:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    //...
});

Task t2 = t1.ContinueWith(t =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("t2 done.");
});
```

The difference is that in the first case you don't have access to the `t1` task, and so you can't `await` it and observe any error that may have occured. Your last chance to observe a possible error was inside the `t2` body, by examining the `IsFaulted`/`Exception` property of the `t` argument. You didn't, so now you'll never know what happened inside the `t1` task.

As a side note the `ContinueWith` is a [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) method, full of gotchas and nuances, and using it in application code is not advisable. If you are writing a library and you are fully aware of its nuances and pitfalls, then this advice doesn't apply. But for general usage, the [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) technology offers everything that you need for writing correct and maintainable asynchronous code.